# C# app with a built-in FTP Server

Tags: c#, ftp

At my work I am writing a C# app, which among its direct functionality should allow user to turn their computer into an FTP server.

Probably it would be more practical to use FileZilla Server, but the I have to aim at really amateur users who are not able to configure FileZilla Server and would like to start an FTP from my soft with one button click.

At the moment I really have no idea, where to start from and asking for some advice.

Comment: [Google](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=c%23%20ftp%20server) is a good place to start, but this format of question isn't a good fit for this site. Do some research, type some code, StackOverflow when the code doesn't work and we can help at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You need to look towards a win32 app published in the Windows Store. The API of apps won't give you enough priviledge for this.